# Why am i able to check multiple radio buttons at once?

Tags: html, radio-button

This is the code i use for my form and I'm using radio button as i know only one can be ticked but for some reason I can click on multiple. How do I fix this?

```
<form name="Question1" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckAnswer1()">

    <input  type="radio" 
     name="Q1opt1" 
     value="1" >Having loads of pictures on the website<br /><br />

    <input  type="radio" 
     name="Q1opt2" 
     value="2" >Making the website nice and pretty.<br /><br />

    <input  type="radio" 
     name="Q1opt3" 
     value="3" >Making the website most user friendly.<br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Select Your Answer and Click Here" />
</form>
```

Comment: Radio buttons must be include in a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) to be exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

They should have the same name but different values, that's how the browser distinguishes between sets of radio button groups:

```
<form name="Question1" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckAnswer1()">

    <input  type="radio" 
     name="Q1opt" 
     value="1" >Having loads of pictures on the website<br /><br />

    <input  type="radio" 
     name="Q1opt" 
     value="2" >Making the website nice and pretty.<br /><br />

    <input  type="radio" 
     name="Q1opt" 
     value="3" >Making the website most user friendly.<br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Select Your Answer and Click Here" />
</form>
```

Comment: function CheckAnswer1()
 {
  if (document.Question1.Q1opt1.checked == true)
 {
  alert ("Sorry, wrong anwser")
 }
  if (document.Question1.Q1opt2.checked == true)
 {
  alert ("No,not this one :/ ")
 }
  if (document.Question1.Q1opt3.checked == true)
 {
  alert ("That is correct!!!")
 }
  return true;
 }                                                                                                                Okay so this is my JavaScript that determines what is the correct answer my the name of the radio button how would i change that so it uses ID or value?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If i'm not mistaken, you can simply ask `document.Question1.Q1opt.value == 1` and so on to determine which, if any, of the radio buttons were checked.

Answer (score 0):

It's because their names are all the same.

Try this:

```
<input type='radio' name='Qstn1' Id='q1Opt1' value='1' />Opt 1<br />
<input type='radio' name='Qstn1' Id='q1Opt2' value='2' />Opt 2<br />
<input type='radio' name='Qstn1' Id='q1Opt3' value='3' />Opt 3<br />
```